# Increasing Weapon Die Size

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

Yesterday I was playing around with the DDI character cuilder and found the Avalanche Hurler <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=paragonpath&id=169)</sup> paragon path for Rangers, so I decided to see what I could do with a ridiculously huge thrown weapon.

Of course, to my dismay, I can't simply increase a d12 to a d20. It would have been hilarious, but that's not how weapon dice sizes work (the progression is d12 → 2d6 → 2d8 → 2d10).

Taking a 2d6 weapon (gouge<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3719)</sup>), making it thrown (Hungry Spear<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1582)</sup>), and using the Avalanche Hurler PP gives me a 2d8 weapon. Is there any way to increase the weapon dice again to reach 2d10, even on a temporary basis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be a Bugbear, and use a large Gouge:

> **Oversized**: You can use weapons of your size or one size larger than you as if they were your size.

With the Eternal Defender epic destiny you can go even higher:
1st level: 2d8
11th level: 2d10
24th level: 2d12

Comment: Does Oversized and Godlike Stature really stack?

Comment: Good question. I would let it stack, if I let you play Bugbear at all.